# Electron,nodejs : App wont start, cannot find app in one of the modules.

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I am trying out an electron app which should point to our website, so I am trying one of the tutorials.. Unfortunately, when I start the app, I get the following error :

Error log :

```
akshay@akshay-mint-desktop ~/electron_tutorial_one $ npm start

> electron_tutorial_one@1.0.0 start /home/akshay/electron_tutorial_one
> electron .

App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module 'app'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/home/akshay/electron_tutorial_one/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/akshay/electron_tutorial_one/index.js:2:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'app'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/home/akshay/electron_tutorial_one/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/akshay/electron_tutorial_one/index.js:2:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
^Cakshay@akshay-mint-desktop ~/electron_tutorial_one $
```

index.js :

```
// Require the libraries used in the app
var app = require('app'),
    BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

require('crash-reporter').start();

var mainWindow = null;

// Kill the app when all windows are closed
app.on('mainWindow-all-closed', function() {
  if (process.platform != 'darwin')
    app.quit();
});

app.on('ready', function() {
  // Create the main window for the app
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    "min-width"         : 800,
    "min-height"        : 600,
    fullscreen          : true,
    resizable           : true,
    "use-content-size"  : true
  });

  // Load in our content
  mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

  // This is required for now due to https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1117
  mainWindow.openDevTools();
  mainWindow.closeDevTools();

  // Ensure that garbage collection occurs when the window is closed
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "electron_tutorial_one",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `require('app')` supposed to do? Is it a npm module? Or a file elsewhere?

Comment: @evolutionxbox : I am new to this, but as far as I know its in index.js given above.

Comment: `var app = require('app')` this says "I require `app`". From what you've written it is not anywhere.

Comment: @evolutionxbox : it's second line in index.js : var app = require('app'),

Comment: Your comment is explaining it - `// Require the libraries used in the app` - Essentially, you're saying "please give me app", but I'm asking where `app` is being defined?

Comment: @evolutionxbox : Where is it generally defined? I am trying this one : http://ryanfrench.co/2015/05/02/harmonic_tutorial_1.html

Comment: [According to the docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app) `app` is a property of `electron`. So you would require it differently, `var electron = require('electron'); var app = electron.app`

Comment: @evolutionxbox : this worked, thanks, but I am getting same for crash-reporter.

Comment: Sounds like the tutorial is out-of-date.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```js
// Require the libraries used in the app
var app = require('app'), BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
```

you should use

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
```

---

You've used a really old example. Electron modules are collected under `'electron'` in [0.35.0](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v0.35.0) more then two years ago ;)

From release notes:

> Add electron module which includes all public APIs.

You'd better use tutorials from electron docs:

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start
https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start